# Angular ui-select not array filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Utilizando ui-select de AngularJS (Angular 1). [Documentacion u-i select angular](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/)

En un input select se quiere mostrar los nombres de los puertos.

```
<li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Port</label>
                <ui-select ng-model="shipmentObject.portArray" theme="bootstrap" style="width:auto;">
                                             <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.shipmentObject.portArray}}</ui-select-match>
                                                <ui-select-choices repeat="item in shipmentObject.portArray | filter: $select.search">

                                                    <div ng-bind-html="item.portName | highlight: $select.search"></div>

                                                    <!-- <small ng-bind-html="item.code | highlight: $select.search"></small> -->

                                                </ui-select-choices>

                                         </ui-select>

                                    </div>
                                    {{item.portName}}
                                </li>
```

Se trae la informacion del backend

```
OptimaResource.getPort(country).then(function(resp){

         // this.portCode=[];
        $scope.shipmentObject.ports = resp.data;
        // console.log($scope.shipmentObject.ports);
        var array = resp.data;

            var resultado = array.map(function(elemento)
            {
                    var dividir = elemento.split("|");
                    return {portCode: dividir[0], portName: dividir[1]};
            });

            $scope.shipmentObject.portArray = resultado;

        // console.log($scope.shipmentObject.portArray);
        // // console.log($scope.shipmentObject.ports);
        // console.log(angular.toJson($scope.shipmentObject.portArray));
        console.log($scope.shipmentObject.portArray);
        console.log($scope.shipmentObject.portArray.data);
        // $scope.shipmentObject.portJson = angular.toJson($scope.shipmentObject.portArray);
        // console.log($scope.shipmentObject.portJson);
        // console.log($scope.shipmentObject.portJson);






    });
```

Al seleccionar un puerto, este no se queda seleccionado en el input y arroja el siguiente error

> Expected array but received: {"portCode":"0106","portName":"HOULTON","$$hashKey":"object:1266"}

Y esto arroja la documentacion sobre este tipo de error

> Description
>   This error occurs when filter is not used with an array:

```
<input ng-model="search">
```

{{ key }} : {{ value }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `ng-model` de la directiva `ui-select` se refiere al objeto que se selecciona, por lo tanto es erróneo hacer el binding a `shipmentObject.portArray`. En el código actual cuando un elemento es seleccionado entonces `shipmentObject.portArray` es reemplazado por el objeto seleccionado y causa el error cuando la directiva `ui-select-choices repeat` intenta leer a `shipmentObject.portArray` nuevamente después del *ciclo de digest*.

Crea una propiedad de `$scope.selected` en el controlador y cambia el `ng-model` de `ui-select`

```
<ui-select ng-model="selected" theme="bootstrap" style="width:auto;">
```

Comment: A que te refieres con crear una propiedad de  `$scope.selected` en el controlador?

Comment: Quizás "crear" no es el termino más adecuado, me refiero a "definir" una propiedad en `$scope` que se llame `selected` (`$scope.selected`) (claro que puedes elegir el nombre que veas conveniente en lugar de `selected`) y asignarle un valor inicial, ya sea `null` o un elemento de `$scope.shipmentObject.portArray`

Comment: La idea de `$scope.selected` es usarlo en el `ng-model` de `ui-select`